# obfuscating with proguard

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

Ok so I have an app I've built in Android Studio, in Java.
It's using Knox, I've tried to obfuscate it using ProGuard and after quite some times I've managed to do so.
I didn't really "managed" I added

> -ignorewarnings

to the .pro file to make it work. I realize that's not a solution but for now, I can't seem to find a way around it. I'm either getting the following error:

> Warning: there were 3296 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
> You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
> If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress

Which I assume is from the obfuscating process, if I'm building the app with

> minifyEnabled false

it's working fine. I tried using the -keep function, which I have no clue how to, I tried the following:

For the warning line:

```
Warning: com.samsung.android.knox.ucm.core.UniversalCredentialUtil: can't find referenced class com.sec.enterprise.knox.ucm.core.UniversalCredentialUtil
```

I tried:

> -keep class com.samsung.android.knox.ucm.core.UniversalCredentialUtil.**

But I still got the same error.
I tried:

> -keep class com.samsung.android.knox.ucm.core.UniversalCredentialUtil.** { *; }

But still same error.
I also tried:

> -keep class com.samsung.android.knox.ucm.core.** { *; }

and

> -keep class com.samsung.android.knox.ucm.core.**

but to no avail.

I tried removing the whole jar from proguard:

```
    -injars      bin/knoxsdk.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

But I'm getting the following:

> The same input jar [...\app\libs\knoxsdk.jar] is specified twice.
> Even though I have no clue where else is it specified.

Anyway, after using the -ignorewarnings mentioned above I've managed to create an APK. I tried checking it with dex2jar but it had issues decompiling it. Nonetheless I've tried putting it on my device, it installed properly and all but it throws an exception:

```
setUsbConnectionType(int) method from a.b.a.a.b.d class is only supported from API level 20 and above (current is 0)
```

I realize setUsbConnectionType is a Knox function, how ever, why am I getting that the current API is 0?

So basically, tl;dr:

1. How do I properly obfuscate my code using ProGuard when I have knox jars in my project.
   OR
2. How do I fix this API error?

Thanks!

Comment: It reads: `there were 3296 unresolved references to classes or interfaces`... this JAR might not be the only issue. Add `-verbose`.

Comment: Yes, they are all warning about classes it cant find, which I assume is due to the obfuscation. All from the knox library